# Dreams about C# precompiler variables

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

We have different output pathes for Debug and for Release build. In some cases we need to use
relative path from the output folder, for example to use large files from repo at runtime in integration tests and not to copy it to the output directory.  But relative path will be different for debug and release. It would be very nice to have some precompiler variable for whole project level. Like in C++ #define:

```
RELATIVE_PATH "../../folder"
```

but on project level for project configuration. Or like C# using alias directive.

```
using RELATIVE_PATH  = "../../folder";
```

on project level, not on level of namespace or compilation unit. Theoretically it is possible to implement such logic for compiler developers, but as I know this is impossible in C#.

I think such problem will have all at some time who are using different output folders for debug and release. Any ideas? (except `#if DEBUG ... #endif` in every place)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @TimS  What is the best way to do what i want? Maybe i just don't know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your relative root to class like Config.cs and write something like this:

```
public static class Config
{
 public static readonly RelativeRoot;
 public static Config()
 {
#if Debug
   RelativeRoot = "..\..\folder"
#else
   RelativeRoot = "..\..\folder"
#endif
 }
}
```

Or add your relative root to App.config and use config switching: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SwitchConfig.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2010 or above, you could use config file transforms.

You create things like appSettings items in the app.config or web.config, and then in the transform file, set the locations for the build type:

http://exceptionalcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/visual-studio-app-config-xml-transformation/

(available for web.config too)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve. If you want to use those files at runtime, you can decide their paths in runtime too. You could make a small class, or a static method somewhere, which is converting a relative path to an absolute one. In that method, you can use the "#if DEBUG" check, to choose the proper base directory. And every other part of your application loads all files through this method, so they doesn't need to know about the whole path magic.